# Killing an ALTER TABLE or DROP INDEX command before it finishes

Tags: mysql

I just ran a query to drop an index, and it was taking so long I killed the query. I'm curious now, did it partially delete the index, or is the index unaffected?

I used `ALTER TABLE` the first time, and `DROP INDEX` the second time, to remove the index, but ended up killing both queries. My understanding of MySQL's approach is that it copies to a temporary table, applies the changes (removing the index) on the temporary table, deletes the original and renames the temporary table. Is this correct? Is it true for both the `ALTER TABLE` and `DROP INDEX` commands, or is it only true for one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, if the default settings are used.

It is possible to configure the database so it will not make (use of) temp table.

You also can look at the result off course to double check

Answer (score 1):

This will rollback everything. There is no such thing as a half completed transaction in a ACID complaint database. It is a all or nothing situation.

Now something your have to remember especially as far as InnoDB is concerned a index is not stored with a table. It is a separate B-Tree structure on disk with pointer to the data in the tables. Thus MySQL will never need to remove the index from the table. It just needs to destroy the index structure.